# Transferring file using SCP command fails with relative path and works with absolute path

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, file-transfer, scp

This is failing. (the file.txt is in the same folder)

```
sudo scp file.txt shahid@11.34.45.23:~/
#gives error Permission denied (publickey).
```

The following works, however, it asks for the local machine password

```
sudo scp me@localhost:/home/file.xt shahid@11.34.45.23:~/
```

Comment: For the **local** machine? This would mean that _sudo_  is asking for the password, and that it is unrelated to `scp`, which would ask for the remote's password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `file.txt` doesn't contain any critical data, change its permissions to allow reading by others:

```
$ sudo chmod 744 file.txt
```

And then try the `scp`.